# Undefined symbols for Android shared library in Unity

Tags: android, c++, unity-game-engine, dynamic-linking

Build of a c++ library for `armeabi-v7a` using standalone toolchain is successful.
However, when loaded in Unity I get missing symbol error:

```
05-11 17:05:32.029 12064 12082 D Unity   : Unable to load library '/data/app/com.xxx.yyy.app-geDNMNRtyT09WKhCcElqhg==/lib/arm/lib***.so', native render plugin support disabled: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZNSsD1Ev" referenced by "/data/app/com.xxx.yyy.app-geDNMNRtyT09WKhCcElqhg==/lib/arm/lib***.so"...
```

which is `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()`.

When checked compiled library with `nm`, I see this symbol indeed undefined:

```
$ nm lib***.so
 U _ZNSsD1Ev
```

I also can see that the library depends on shared `libstdc++.so`:

```
$ readelf -d build/lib/lib***.so 
...
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libsqlite3.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libopenssl.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libndn-cpp.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [liblog.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libOpenSLES.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libstdc++.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libdl.so]
...
```

even though I setup autotools with `-static-libstdc++`:

```
CFLAGS="-isystem $TOOLCHAIN/include/c++/4.9.x/ --sysroot=$TOOLCHAIN/sysroot -I$TOOLCHAIN/sysroot/usr/include -I$TOOLCHAIN/include"
CPPFLAGS="-isystem $TOOLCHAIN/include/c++/4.9.x/ --sysroot=$TOOLCHAIN/sysroot -I$TOOLCHAIN/sysroot/usr/include -I$TOOLCHAIN/include -DWEBRTC_POSIX -DBOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_STD_CHRONO $CPPFLAGS -DWEBRTC_POSIX -DBOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_STD_CHRONO -g -O0"
CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -DWEBRTC_POSIX -DBOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_STD_CHRONO -g -O0"
LDFLAGS="-static-libstdc++ -L$TOOLCHAIN/sysroot/usr/lib -L$TOOLCHAIN/arm-linux-androideabi/lib -L$TOOLCHAIN/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/armv7-a -lOpenSLES -lm -lsqlite3 -lopenssl"
```

What's interesting, is that when I search toolchain's libraries, the missing symbol shows up only in `libgnustl_shared.so`:

```
$ nm $TOOLCHAIN/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/armv7-a/libgnustl_shared.so | grep "_ZNSsD1Ev"
00096568 W _ZNSsD1Ev
```

Not quite sure why is this happening, as there is no (obvious) dependency on `libgnustl_shared.so` as far as I can tell.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue? I also have an issue with missing symbols in Unity